# Mismatch with Dlookup using multiple criteria and Yes/NO

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a table that has multiple booths assigned to a process and a Yes/NO field for the primary booth for that process.

Process | Booth | Primary

Buff1   |   8   |   No

Buff1  |    5   |  Yes

etc.

I am trying to automate a form to fill in the primary booth on a field when the process gets selected using Dlookup.

This is the code I am using:
        Me.Booth.Value = DLookup("Booth", "BoothSource", "BoothSource.Process = '" & Me.Process & "' AND BoothSource.Primary = '" & "True" & "'")

I am sure it is the Yes/No field that I'm having problems with. Please help.

Comment: On the chance that the issue is partly due to it being on a subform, I also tried this code:

        [Forms]![Part_Process_Form].[subBooth_Process_Multi].Form![Booth] = DLookup("Booth", "BoothSource", "BoothSource.Process = '" & [Forms]![Part_Process_Form].[subBooth_Process_Multi].Form![Process] & "' AND BoothSource.Primary = True")

Comment: Doing more research and I found that my issue could be that I am trying to set the value in a multi-valued combo box. Booth is set to accept multiple booths for assignment and I want to pre-select the primary booth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*True* is not a string, so:

```
Me.Booth.Value = DLookup("Booth", "BoothSource", "BoothSource.Process = '" & Me.Process & "' AND BoothSource.Primary = True")
```

Normally, table name is left out in the criteria:

```
Me!Booth.Value = DLookup("Booth", "BoothSource", "[Process] = '" & Me!Process.Value & "' AND [Primary] = True")
```

Comment: With that change I get error "3032 Cannot perform this operation."

Comment: Would it make a difference if the form I am using is a subform? That is where this is all taking place.  Main form is Part_Process_Form and the subform is subBooth_Process_Multi.

Comment: I think `Process` is numerical, remove the quotes there, then it might work. However, this error is a bit odd. I've never encountered it before, and would expect a type mismatch error if this problem caused it.

Comment: Sorry, I probably should have entered my example differently. Process is text, Booth is Numeric, and the Primary field is Yes/No.

Comment: See edited answer. Also, Me!Booth must, of course, be updatable.

Comment: Nope. same error. Cannot perform this operation. I'm now thinking it has to do with Booth being a multi-select field.

Comment: I'm going to mark this as correct, since it did answer the original problem. I'll re-ask the question in regards to the multi-select problem. Thank you all!

Comment: If anyone is interested, here is a link to the new question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49326189/set-subform-multi-select-field-using-dlookup