# Set subform multi-select field using Dlookup

Tags: ms-access, sharepoint, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a table that has multiple booths assigned to a process and a Yes/NO field for the primary booth for that process.

Process | Booth | Primary

Buff1 | 8 | No

Buff1 | 5 | Yes

etc.

I am trying to automate a form to select the primary booth on a multiselect field when the process gets selected using Dlookup.

This is the code I am using:

```
Me.Booth.Value = DLookup("Booth", "BoothSource", "BoothSource.Process = '" & Me.Process & "' AND BoothSource.Primary = True")
```

The Booth field is a multi-select field. And I get error 3032 Cannot perform this operation when I try to test. Please help.
[Multi-Select Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VoKgM.png)

Comment: That's not how multi-select fields work. Is `Booth` a list box? You will likely need some more complex VBA.

Comment: It's a multi-value field. like a list box but different.

Comment: See linked image above. "Multi-Select Example"

Comment: Eh... Is that a form in datasheet view? If you're using datasheet view, that's a _very_ relevant detail, and makes all further code way harder.

Comment: Why is that? I have never had issues with it in the past? What am I missing?

Comment: If you're using a form in datasheet view, there's only one instance of every control being used for multiple records. That means that when changing a control, it affects all records at once, and that leads to trouble when setting the controls value property to something that's dependent on a value in the record.

Comment: Are you referring to rowsource? I have code that changes the rowsource on focus. The form has been working flawlessly until it was requested to automatically select the primary booth.

Comment: You can dynamically change row source and other things.  Just not the value property if you want to affect a specific record or want to change it to a value dependent on another value in that record.

Comment: I changed the form to Single Form and tested but still get the same result. I'm positive it is related to the multi-select field. I have tried assigning the index of the field first also and still no luck.

Comment: Yes, but now I can actually answer it. Give me a moment to write up a good answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multi-select fields and combo boxes are very hard to work with.

The `.Value` property of a multi-valued combo box is apparently a variant array, and writeable. You can set the `.Value` property equal to an array containing your value, instead of just your value.

Note that this bypasses many checks, such as the `Limit to list` property, even if value edits to the list are disallowed. You should check your inputs manually, since this might cause errors. Avoid including anything other than a string in your array (numbers, dates), since these will not trigger an error, but insert anything from `Null` to some item on your list to pseudorandom unicode characters.

```vb
Dim varValue As Variant
varValue = DLookup("Booth", "BoothSource", "BoothSource.Process = '" & Me.Process & "' AND BoothSource.Primary = True")
Me.Booth.Value = Array(CStr(varValue))
```

Note that I strongly advice against using multi select fields, so you can avoid this mess.

Comment: I get error 3061: Too few parameters. Expected 1.

rs = nothing when I look at the debugger.

The lookup and the form source are different tables, if that helps. The form is based on table "Booth_Process_Multi" this is the table that has the multiselect field. The table BoothSource does not.

Comment: Sounds like your input parameter (`Me.Process`) doesn't evaluate to a valid value. Does it contain apostrophes?

Comment: No, it's selected with a combobox. I added a debug.print for the field and it's populated as expected.

Comment: ... If that's a multi-select field too, I'm going to abandon this. Can you `Debug.Print Me.Process`?

Comment: I was typing that as you posted. :) It is not a multi select field

Comment: I am now getting the same error but with Expected 2. I also did a debug.print and the value is still present. rs is still nothing

Comment: Can I get the structure of that `BoothSource` table? I have the feeling your dlookup was never going to work.

Comment: BoothID = Autonumber, PK

Booth = Number

Process = Text

Primary = Yes/No

Comment: I did a test with the original code and replaced the field I want to populate with a variable and had it print it. The dlookup is working. It's when it is assigned to the multiselect field that it is failing.

        Dim intTest As Integer
    If [Forms]![Part_Process_Form].[subBooth_Process_Multi].Form![Process] <> "" Then
        intTest = DLookup("Booth", "BoothSource", "BoothSource.Process = '" & Me.Process & "' AND BoothSource.Primary = True")
    End If
    Debug.Print intTest

Comment: In meeting, will answer soon. So you're not trying to look up a multi valued field but a single value, and check that in your multi valued field?

Comment: Now I'm getting error 424 Object required on line 

If varValue = MS.ItemData(i)

varValue has the correct data but (i) is 0 and ListCount is 2

Comment: Ah, sorry, I forgot to replace my control name with yours there.

Comment: No errors but it did not perform as hoped. Instead we only got the dropdown for booth with no items selected.

Comment: Does the string you just looked up occur in the possible options?

Comment: Yes it does. I have 2 possible selections with the process I chose. The primary one is listed first, but that may not always be the case.

Comment: Can you give me the string for that `DLookUp`?

Comment: The original code? the varValue = 21 which is the primary booth for the process selected.

Comment: The result is the same as varValue, 21
I also did a debug.print on me.booth.itemdata(i) and it did not show me anything. Is that not a valid option for debug?

Comment: Try the current edit. I've noticed `.ItemData` sometimes does really strange things, and `.Column` doesn't. They should return the same, as long as the first argument of `.Column` is the bound column, but they don't.

Comment: No errors, same as before. Dropdown was shown but no selection. debug.print for me.booth.column(1, i) shows nothing

Comment: Then I'm at a loss. `Me.Booth.Column(1,1)` should return the second value of your combo box. `Me.Booth.ListCount` should return the amount of items. Can you verify that?

Comment: List count is giving me the correct value; 2

I'm at a loss. I have been trying to find how to refer to a multivalue field in vba. All I'm finding is how to set up the field in the table. I might just have to tell the client that it can't be done without redefining the current tables.

Comment: Well, it can. In my test setup it works just fine. What does `Me.Booth.Column(1,1)` return?

Comment: I wonder, is it possible to bold the correct value only in the dropdown. Maybe not select it, but change it's formatting?

Comment: Nope. That's not possible. You have no control over formatting in a combo box

Comment: It returns the second option item, which is not the primary?

Comment: Yeah, I didn't think so. Just grasping at straws.

Comment: Eh... It should return the second item from the first column, that's right. `Me.Booth.Column(1,0)` should return 21 as far as I can tell

Comment: If I create a query on the multiselect field it needs to refer to field.[value] not just the field. If I look at the SQL it has field.value as field.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Can you try the current edit, and give me the returns from the `Debug.Print`?

Comment: 21 and 22 respectively

Comment: Eh.... That should return a lot more than that (it should return something for every row). But if it returns 21, it also should select 21 if varValue is 21. I guess I'll leave it, as I can't reproduce any of this since the last 6 comments.

Comment: There are only the two options for selection with the process I chose. If I choose a different process I could have more.

Comment: I think I'm going to call it a night. I do appreciate all the time you have devoted to helping me find a solution. I would buy you a drink or two if I could.

Comment: Good night. I still don't understand what's happening. Funny fact: `VarType(Me.Booth.Value)` should return 8204, and that variable type doesn't exist according to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/vartype-function). Multi-select combo boxes are very, very weird

Comment: Oh, I just discovered the `.Value` property behaves like a string array. Why, and why that's not documented, I don't know. But it might fix the problem. You can try the current edit tomorrow.

Comment: I just tried your latest edit. Same results. Sorry. ;(

Comment: Edited just now :), you were too soon

Comment: Well, just glad I got it in the end :) after all that misunderstanding. I still have no clue why the other attempts failed, but this one also is way simpler than any other I made before.

Comment: I could kiss you! Thank you so, so much!

Comment: You are lucky that @ErikvonAsmuth is around.